# Laravel Cashier create more relationships with a subscription

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to create one more relationship with my subscriptions, the first one is **user** which is the billable model and it's working fine, the other one is **place**, which is the place the user owns.

I created a migration which adds the place_id:

```
    Schema::table('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('place_id')->nullable()->after('user_id');


        $table->index('place_id');
    });
```

**I can't find a way to make the subscription->place relationship, where do i create it?** The place->subscription relationship works fine. Do i create another model? With namespace Laravel\Cashier?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a normal model that extends `Laravel\Cashier\Subscription`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Cashier\Subscription as CashierSubscription;

class Subscription extends CashierSubscription
{
    public function place()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Place');
    }

    public function plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plan', 'stripe_plan', 'stripe_id');
    }

    public function getRenewsAtAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->asStripeSubscription()->current_period_end);
    }

    // ...
}
```